# Could not execute tests on remote machine using selenium grid

Tags: eclipse, selenium-grid2

I have written the code to run tests in parallel.I have started selenium hub on my ubuntu machine and registered 2 nodes to it one node from virtual machine and another node from different system.My code is working on node running on virtual machine but doesn't run on remote machine.

**Here is my code**

```
package com.example.selenium;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

    public class ParllelTest {
        static RemoteWebDriver driver;

      @BeforeTest (alwaysRun=true)
      @Parameters({"platform","browserName","remoteurl"})
      public void beforeTest(String platform,String browserName,String remoteurl) throws MalformedURLException {
          DesiredCapabilities cap = null;


          if(browserName.equals("firefox")) {

              cap=new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();


          cap.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
          cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
          }

          else if(browserName.equals("firefox"))
          {
              cap=new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();

              cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
              cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);
          }


          driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteurl),cap);
      }
      @Test
      public void googlesearch() 
      {


          driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
          driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxx");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxx");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.findElement(By.id("click")).click();
      }
    }
```

**And corresponding xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests" >
<test verbose="3" name="Vista">
<paramaters>
   <parameter name="platform" value="VISTA"/>
   <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
   <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://10.X.X.X:5557/wd/hub"/>
</paramaters>
<classes>
    <class name="com.example.selenium.ParllelTest">
     <method>
        <include name="googlesearch"/>
      </method>   
    </class>
</classes>
</test>
<test verbose="3" name="windows">
 <paramaters>
   <parameter name="platform" value="WIN8"/>
   <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
   <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://10.X.X.X:5553/wd/hub"/>
</paramaters>
<classes>
    <class name="com.example.selenium.ParllelTest">
       <method>
        <include name="googlesearch"/>
      </method>   
     </class>
</classes>
</test>
```

Here is the specification of remote machine where iam trying to run the test firefox version:44 selenium jar:2.53.0 platform:Windows 8

Iam getting following error while trying to run the test

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Though i can use chrome browser on my remote machine problem is i want execute tests on more than 10 devices in parallel so setting chrome driver path in every machine would be hectic task. Iam stuck here can someone help me ?

Comment: When you looked at the node logs of your remote machine (Win8) what did you see ? It looks like startSession() which starts a new browser instance is crashing here.

Comment: I didnt see any activity in the remote machine terminal .Still stuck with the issue

Comment: Have you found any answer to this question